# Rate content and attribute points to author

Tags: 7, rating

I am looking for a module that allows users to be rated points +1 -1 . Any suggestions?  I would like individual users to be rated like stack exchange. I would also eventually like to have a rating for a node, e.g. project which also contributes to the user's points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [User Points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module. For node ratings you can use the [User points Nodes and Comments](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_nc) or/and the [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) modules. There are also plenty of other modules that integrate with the User Points module, there's a nice list in the [User Points Contributed modules](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that information. The User points nodes and comments modules solves one of my problems. That a user who posts a node can receive points. I also want to be able to give a  user points when someone votes on the node they posted. I am trying to achieve this using: rules, rules userpoints, rules voting, and applying an action for this. Is this something possible?

Comment: I acheived this with the rating module, rules and userpoints in the end.